# Framework for large(r) C#-Applications

Tags: software-development, c#, framework

Our current application suite is now growing over 20 years and is written in C#(*) and consists of ~20 larger or smaller applications. We plan to rewrite a larger part of our software suite because of marketing requirements and combine them into a single one. On the long term, we might want to get everything into a single .exe. We see this as a chance to get rid of some of our sins and sins of our predecessors. But we build our applications the same way we have done so the last decade (still WinForms and MainForm.cs spanning several thousands of lines on many of our application).

What are modern, futureproof ways of creating larger C#-applications. Suggestions like

- Frameworks/ libraries
- Blogs with experinces about this topic
- book-recomondations
- things I forgot

are welcome. If this matters: the software is running locally with no server/ cloud involved and is used to control machines.

(*) mostly C#, older applications using Borland C++ (yuk!) are rewritten in C#/ Visual Studio over time but this is a ongoing process.

Comment: Asking for books is off-topic. Asking for blogs is also off-topic. Asking for things you can't even describe will  not give you the answer you want. So, the framework part remains and that is too broad.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I do not ask for a complete solution just for pointers where to get started. SE decided to split SO into a few dozen of sites. On SO itself, everything gets downvoted and closed except a very narrow band of questions fitting their definition of ontopic (a for me helpfull question on SO is closed as off-topic 5 of 10 times). Sooooo .. where would this be ontopic=?

Comment: I'm active on multiple sites and all of them have the "too broad" close reason. And I'm sure it would be closed on all sites. Your requests looks like you and/or your colleagues have a huge task and no idea on how to approach it. This needs consulting and skill improvements, not an answer. You do not only need a library, you also need tools. The sentence "things I forgot" indicates that you have not yet analyzed the problem in depth. Otherwise you would be sure that you have covered all requirements. A suggestion: use the trial period to watch https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/brownfield

Comment: @ThomasWeller: you are right, we currently have no idea how to approach the task. But we are also far from actively working in it (currently we try to find out what we want and even that is in an early phase. How we want it including a in-depth-analysis is for later). Thanks for your link, I'll take a look. A consultant has also been in discussion.

Comment: I can only suggest Googling for blogs, and sorting Amazon book search results by reader recommendations. I feel your pain, but don't know where else to ask.  Even for frameworks, you would need to define features for us to recommend one. Hopefully, your consultant will help.